# .NET Core 3 Razor pages app - Authorize all pages within an Area

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to lock access to all the pages in selected Areas in my Razor Pages app. So far I have this sample structure

**Areas**

- **Account**

  - Index.chtml
- **Business**

  - Index.chtml

If I add

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/business", "/index");
```

to startup, it works on a per page basis, but I cant see any clear way to lock the entire Business folder.
I've tried the folder based options mentioned here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0

but none seem to work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So 10 seconds after asking, this works

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("business", "/");
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this

Comment: You should accept your own answer, it definitely works.